# SetProcessMitigationPolicy - How can I avoid the pop-up and have control in my program?

Tags: windows, security, dll, policy

The code below works as expected. If a DLL not signed by Microsoft is loaded, an error message appears.

```
PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY sp = {0};
sp.MicrosoftSignedOnly = 1;
SetProcessMitigationPolicy(ProcessSignaturePolicy, &sp, sizeof(sp));

HMODULE hLib = NULL;
hLib = LoadLibraryExW(L"C:\\tmp\\\my.dll", 0, 0);
```

[image]

How can I avoid a system generated pop up and have control in my program. I tried it with a with an exception handler which did not work. Thanks for your help.

I searched on the internet and I could not find any solution

Comment: `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);`